# Zend Framework Dynamic Routing

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I have a website that is purely database driven. I m new to Zend Framwork, and to the concept of routing, though I have been doing a lot of reading. Brain is pretty much a sponge, with some stuff still trying to be comprehended. I am using ZF mainly for the routing, though I plan to implement other aspects of it when I can. For the most part it is a learning process, so there are some things I will want to write myself without the framework.

Here’s how the site should work:
URLs could be anything from “/” - a root index, to
“/contact/ - a root file, to
 “/deposits/” – a sub-directory to
“/deposits/ira/” - a file in the sub directory.

When a user clicks on a link code will need to parse the REQUEST_URI in order to look into the “pages” table of the database. The sole purpose for this is to get the ID of the record matching the REQUEST_URI. That ID is the key to everything for the page, and other tables are then checked to see if there is any data for other aspects of the page that need to be gotten. The immediate need is for the template name. The site will have a few different pages that are used depending on if it is a home page, section landing page, or content of a section. This information is decided upon when a page is saved to the DB.

I want to be able to take this data and then decide how to route it so that it uses the correct template and can collect the rest of the data from that point to complete the page.

Since sections and pages can be created at any time, there must be controllers that can handle what to do based on the returned template data. This pretty much means the controllers and such will need some standardized names that are non-specific to what values passed in the REQUEST_URI.

How would I accomplish this in Zend so that all this happens before the controller is selected, and only having template names to go by for selecting the correct controller?

Thanks,
Cy

Comment: Are you using the Zend Framework MVC? If not you'll need to write your own Dispatcher and router. There is a reason that the dispatcher and router do not have their own components.

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly the case that *all* your routes (at least for the frontend) are dynamic, then it sounds like you could do this:

1. On bootstrap, remove all default routes.
2. In a plugin on `routeStartup`, grab the `REQUEST_URI` and query your db. Presumably that record contains enough info for you to figure out the required controller, action, layout, etc.

   2.1 Add a single route (matching the REQUEST_URI) mapping to the controller and action.

   2.2 Set the layout to be the required layout.

Then during normal dispatch, the route will match, the controller/action will be invoked and you'll have the layout set correctly.

If the request doesn't match any page stored in your db, you'll have to invoke the error controller/action yourself to give a 404 response.

However, if you eventually have some static (that is, non-db-stored) routes in your app (which I imagine must be the case), then you'll want to match against them before you hit the db to search for the requested one. That matching sounds like a pain (though perhaps there is a way to ask the router itself if the requested route matches, just like the standard dispatcher does).

In that case, perhaps an alternative approach would be to add all those (non-db-stored) routes to the router in the standard way at bootstrap, and put all this `REQUEST_URI` inspection, db-searching, and controller/action/layout handling in the 404 handler. If the requested url matches something in your db, then `_forward()` (not redirect) to that controller/action and set the layout, as above.

It's probably not the most performant solution- since `_forward()` triggers another iteration in the dispatch loop -  but it seems like it could work.